# How to authenticate a PHP website using users in Samba4 AD

Tags: php, samba

I have seen a couple of websites / tutorials to "access files and folders" controlled by Samba4.

I want to ask if it is possible to use Samba as the database, and allow a user to enter their username and password, then using PHP, connect to the Samba users list to check these credentials and authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this looong time ago with samba3 and PHP4. Sorry but I can't give you details right now but I used this: 
http://uranus.chrysocome.net/linux/php/php_smbauth.htm

Code will be like:

```
smbauth($username, $password, $primary_svr, $secondary_svr, $domain);
```

I didn't see support for PHP5 or if it is possible to install it via apt. Anyway, with the source and administrative privileges you can compile it.

Comment: Thanks, i will have a look at this, and possibly attempt implementation on PHP5 and Samba4 maybe? If anyone has this configuration already, or details on what to NOT do and what to consider, they can further add here. Would be grateful.